# How to make react-native-voice work in background mode?

Tags: react-native, phone-call, react-native-voice

This below code is my codes. i don't know how can i next step for working in background mode in react-native for react-native-voice. would you check my codes

```
import Voice from '@react-native-voice/voice';
import BackgroundService from 'react-native-background-actions';

const sleep = (time) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), time));

const veryIntensiveTask = async (taskDataArguments) => {
  // Example of an infinite loop task
  const { delay } = taskDataArguments;
  await new Promise( async (resolve) => {
      for (let i = 0; BackgroundService.isRunning(); i++) {
          console.log(i);
  
          await Voice.start('ko-KR');
          console.log('voice check');

          console.log("voiceLabel",voiceLabel);
      
           //you can call spi here
          await BackgroundService.updateNotification({taskDesc: 'my counter is running' + i}); 
          await sleep(delay);
      }
  });
};
  



  const startBackgroundService = async () => {
    console.log('test');
    await BackgroundService.start(veryIntensiveTask, options);
    await BackgroundService.updateNotification({taskDesc: 'my counter is running'}); 
  
  
    };

    const stopBackgroundService = async () =>{
      await BackgroundService.stop();
    };


  useEffect(() => {
    Voice.onSpeechStart = _onSpeechStart;
    Voice.onSpeechEnd = _onSpeechEnd;
    Voice.onSpeechResults = _onSpeechResults;
    Voice.onSpeechError = _onSpeechError;
```

I try to like this, but this way bouble onSpeechStart.